# How to add dividers or spacers with text to a recylerview which dynamically adapts to status attribute

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I've got a RecylerView that is displaying a list of data. I need to add dividers or spacers that I need to add two Dividers or spacers too that I can add text [Present and Invited] the header should dynamically adapt to status of the item present in the list. As the person joins the party they should move from invite to present

** Note : Invites can are size can increase or decrease as well as Present with respect to status of the item **

I have achieved the following but the alignment wont fit for dynamic changes

Pls refer the image for clarity :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mssFl.gif

SeparationDecorator class :

```
public class SeparationDecorator extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private int textSize = 50;
    private int groupSpacing = 100;

    private static int printPresentAt;
    private static int printInviteAt;

    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    {
        paint.setTextSize(textSize);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {

        // TODO : Allignment Problem

        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {

            View view = parent.getChildAt(i);
            int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);

            int present = MyGlobal.getPresentCount();
            int invited = MyGlobal.getInviteCount();

            if(present == 0 && invited>0){
                SeparationDecorator.printPresentAt = invited;
                SeparationDecorator.printInviteAt = 0;
            } else if (present > 0 && invited>0) {
                SeparationDecorator. printPresentAt = 0;
                SeparationDecorator.printInviteAt = present;
            } else if (present > 0 && invited == 0) {
                SeparationDecorator.printPresentAt = 0;
                SeparationDecorator.printInviteAt = present;
            }

            if (position == SeparationDecorator.printPresentAt) {
                c.drawText("Present", view.getLeft(),
                        view.getTop() - groupSpacing + textSize, paint);
            } else {
                if(position == SeparationDecorator.printInviteAt) {
                    c.drawText("Invited", view.getLeft(),
                            view.getTop() - groupSpacing + textSize, paint);
                }
            }


        }
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == SeparationDecorator.printInviteAt
                ||parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == SeparationDecorator.printPresentAt) {
            outRect.set(0, groupSpacing, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

MyGlobal.getPresentCount() is the count of present members
MyGlobal.getInviteCount() is the count of invited members
** They will change dynamically **

Item class :

```
public class FriendsModel {

    String userName;
    String handleName;
    int status;
    /*
    *   0 - Invited
    *   1 - Accepted
    *
    * */
    String fcm;

    String uid;

    public FriendsModel(String userName, String handleName, int status, String fcm, String uid) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.handleName = handleName;
        this.status = status;
        this.fcm = fcm;
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public FriendsModel() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        FriendsModel model = (FriendsModel) obj;

        if(this.uid.equals(model.uid))
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    /* All getters and setters */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

need reattach adapter

```
recycleView.adapter = null
recycleView.adapter = adapter
```

Comment: Still No change